# Yarn not recognizing built in package?

Tags: yarnpkg, dependency-management, history.js, yarnpkg-v2

I have the following code snippet in my app:

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/dev' });
```

This function, and its typings, exist in `node_modules` under `history` and `@types/history`:

```js
export interface BrowserHistoryBuildOptions {
    basename?: string;
    forceRefresh?: boolean;
    getUserConfirmation?: typeof getConfirmation;
    keyLength?: number;
}

export default function createBrowserHistory<S = LocationState>(options?: BrowserHistoryBuildOptions): History<S>;
```

I am now trying to migrate to Yarn 2 with PnP and in that, trying to fix anything `yarn dlx @yarnpkg/doctor` finds, as per Yarn's migration tutorial. And the doctor found that this `history` is an undeclared dependency.

```sh
Undeclared dependency on history
```

So I `yarn add`ed `history` and unfortunately, the actual `history` library is incopatible with the function we're using in this app (takes `window` as an argument, instead of the above `options`.

```js
export declare type BrowserHistoryOptions = {
    window?: Window;
};
export declare function createBrowserHistory(options?: BrowserHistoryOptions): BrowserHistory;
```

I don't really know what I'm looking for here. This usage of ours works well, but Yarn doesn't recognize this as a thing and instead thinks it's an undeclared dependency. But, adding the dependency breaks our function usage.
How do I fix this situation?